# Set timeout for FOR LOOP in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a task that need to repeat 1000 times, but sometime it gets stuck in For Loop, so I want to set timeout for it , for example, after 30 sec if the job is not done, script will continue

```
profile = [p for p in range(1000,2000)]
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(Len(profile)):
    current_time = time.time()
    if current_time - start_time > 20:
         break # if break here the whole loop will stop not only iteration that take longer than 20
    else: 
        #do my job here, it usually takes 10 sec to complete
        #but for some reasons, It may stuck here forever
        #how to set a timeout, if it takes more than 20 sec, script will continue next iteration of the loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `time` module:

```py
import time

start = time.time()
for i in range(1000,2000):
     if (time.time() - start) > 20:
         break
```

Comment: this will work if I use While loop, but for loop, it only check time once, after time checked my job still run longer than time condition :(

Comment: What do you mean by checks the time only once? it checks every iteration of the loop, so if an iteration takes longer it'll only stop on the next one. Can you include the rest of the code so i can take a look?

Comment: I changed my code, please take a look